# How I can delete characters in text file lines using sed?

Tags: sed

I have a text file containing urls.

```
1,https://cinesmovies/i/3juj2i,,
1,https://cinesmovies/i/3juj2j,,
1,https://cinesmovies/i/3juj2k,,
1,https://cinesmovies/i/3juj2l,,
```

I want to delete first 2 characters and last 2 characters from every line. those "1," at beginning and ",," at last from every line using sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with sed for such a simple case...

```
$ cut -d, -f2 <filename
```

... will do the job.

`-d` defines the field delimiter, `,` in this case
`-f` defines what to cut out, field `2` in this case

*Know the tools you have available, use the simplest one...*

Comment: I want to implement it on a .text file, above works but only display result on screen. I tried                                
 $cut -i -d, -f2 <links.txt
cut: invalid option -- 'i'
Try 'cut --help' for more information.

Comment: So? Where is the problem using a temporary file? ;-)

Comment: I want to do same on multiple text files.

Comment: And that is by no means impossible with the above...

Comment: www.tldp.org -> Bash guides -- already just skimming through them will  elevate your bash programming knowledge, looping over a bunch of files is basic stuff. Doable with a "oneliner".

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -i -E 's/..(.*)../\1/' filename
```

This keeps only the part between the first two and last two characters.